# Entity manager Null pointer exception - java code configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Im trying to build WebApp with Spring MVC and Hibernate. All configuration is by java code (no XML config files).

When I'm using entity manager (example of using in post below) it throws null pointer exception on persist method - but if I use select query on entity manager it works fine.

Here is my MVC configuration:

```
package com.test.Config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new 
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");     
    }

}
```

ApplicationContextConfig.java:

```
package com.test.Config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.Test.Controllers"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

     private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
         properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
         "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
         return properties;
     }

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
         InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = 
         new InternalResourceViewResolver();
         viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
         viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
         return viewResolver;
    }


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
         BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
         dataSource.setUsername("root");
         dataSource.setPassword("admin");

         return dataSource;
    }


    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

         LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = 
         new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

         sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.Test.Models");
         sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

         return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
        SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }   

}
```

Here is example of using entity manager:

```
package com.Test.TestPackage;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.Test.Models.User;

@Transactional
public class TestEntityManager {

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManager; 

     public void addUser(User tmp) {
          // throws null pointer exception  
          entityManager.persist(tmp);   
     }

     public User QueryUser(int id){
          // works fine
          List results = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u 
          where u.Id = :id", User.class).setParameter("id", id)
                                        .getResultList();

          if(results.isEmpty()) return null; 
          else return (User) results.get(0); 
    }       

}
```

What is missing in my config or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *it throws null pointer exception on persist method* - what `persist` method - I can not see it.  Where is the exception stacktrace ?

Comment: Don't post additional info as an answer. Also you want to use an `EntityManager` then why are you configuring a `SessionFactory`?